# Is it possible to estimate total heterogeneity (I^2) from a model fitted with 'rma.mv' in metafor?

Tags: r, meta-analysis

Estimating mean pooled effect size in meta-analysis can be done via `rma.uni` function. The output provide statistics that can be used to assess total heterogeneity, i.e. I^2. However, say I want to use a null model via `rma.mv` instead which estimates the pooled effect size without any moderator included but allows to specify the random component. In that case I^2 statistic is not provided by the model.

Is there a reason why?

Comment: You might want to post questions about using metafor to the R mailing list on meta-analysis stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis/ you do need to register first.

Comment: Do you get same  mean effect-size for the two ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no all-encompassing generalization of the $I^2$ statistic for models that can be fitted with `rma.mv()` -- it can fit many different kinds of models (multilevel, multivariate, network meta-analysis, phylogenetic meta-analysis, etc.) and I do not want to decide for the user how an $I^2$-like statistic should be computed for the user in those cases and I see no way of automating a sensible decision rule. Also, generalizations of $I^2$ to more complex models is an ongoing research topic. For now, you might want to take a look at my write up of some possible ways of computing $I^2$ for multilevel and multivariate models that you can find on the metafor website:

http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:i2_multilevel_multivariate